# How to use Python in the Linux command

Tags: python, linux, awk

I'm used to writing a lot of AWK commands, but, always wanted to use Python to do the same stuff that i do with Awk **without writing a .py file**. I have basics in the Python, but not in the command line.

For example I have the following  AWK command. What is the equivalent for python?

```
awk '/Classic.java/ {print $0}' somefile.log;
```

Comment: is `python -c "print(expression)"` the sort of thing you want?

Comment: @FoxWilson I'm trying to understand how to do basic search and word processing on log files using python. See my update, that is how the awk will search and print the matching line from the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code translation service or a tutorial service.

Comment: ....I'm trying to come up with good way to do what you want, but `somefile.log> python3 -c "import re; import sys; [print(i) for i in sys.stdin if re.search('Classic.java', i)]"` requires piping, and looks real silly :P. Just use awk, python's not really meant for stuff like this.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen thank you much for the reply, that is what i've expected, i've written a python something like that, was looking for ways to use python in these type of stuff as i hear it is versatile, and it was lengthy compared to awk or sed.

Comment: Think of the command line as a specialized IDE, and the question as a request to find a convenient, unix-like way to use python via that IDE.  The pyline / pyp answer is exactly that - letting programmers easily use their knowledge of python to filter or mapreduce stuff via the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is not very suitable for shell one-liners. You could play with [The Pyed Piper](https://code.google.com/p/pyp/):

```
$ ls | pyp "p[0] | pp.sort() | p + ' first letter, sorted!'"
  # it gives sorted list of first letters of every line
```

It uses standard Python string and list methods as well as custom functions. There is also [pyline](https://github.com/westurner/pyline):

```
$ ls | pyline -m os 'line and os.path.abspath(line.strip())'
$ ls | pyline -r '\(.*\)' 'rgx and (rgx.group(0), rgx.group(1)) or line'
$ ls | pyline -p 'p and p.abspath() or ("# ".format(line))'
```

Another alternative is to use [`ipython` as a shell](http://ipython.org/) or a browser-based [notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) (recommended). Or if you want more BASHwards-looking syntax and tab completion for subprocess commands; try [`xonsh` as your shell](http://xonsh.org/index.html):

```
xonsh$ [i*i for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
xonsh$ date -u
Tue Oct  6 04:25:27 UTC 2015
```

[`subprocess` and its alternatives (`plumbum`, `pexpect`, `sarge`, `sh` (module), `fabric`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768716/4279) allow you to create arbitrary complex commands by exploiting the best of python and bash.

There are also several [nice `python -m` one-liners](http://pythonwise.blogspot.ru/2015/01/python-m.html) e.g.:

```
$ python3 -m http.server # serve current directory over http
$ python -m zipfile # work with zipfiles
$ python -m calendar # show calendar
$ python -m telnetlib towel.blinkenlights.nl # Star Wars
```

Comment: You made the question a helpful, worthy question via this epic answer (truly, given the ability to watch Star Wars via python on the console)!