# Alternative in python to subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to write a script which has to make a lot of calls to some bash commands, parse and process the outputs and finally give some output.

I was using subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call

If I understand correct these methods spawn a bah process, run the command, get the output and then kill the process.

Is there a way to have a bash process running in the background continuously and then the python calls could just go directly to that process? This would be something like bash running as a server and python calls going to it.

I feel this would optimize the calls a bit as there is no bash process setup and teardown. Or will it give no performance advantage?

Comment: Do you actually need a shell to run the commands?  `subprocess` only spawns a shell if you actually ask it to (`shell=True` option) -- or if the command is a shell it self:  `Popen('bash ...')`.

Comment: If you're writing a Python script that connects various shell commands, perhaps the [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [sh.py](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/index.html) packages could be of (better) use to you.

Comment: Worried about performance? Don't guess, profile it and see what happens.

Comment: "some bash commands" are very likely *not* bash commands (built into bash).  Do you homework and *learn*, and *then* come here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I understand correct these methods spawn a bah process, run the command, get the output and then kill the process.

`subprocess.Popen` is a bit more involved. It actually creates an I/O thread to avoid deadlocks. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/:

> A `communicate()` method, which makes it easy to send `stdin` data and read `stdout` and `stderr` data, without risking deadlocks. Most people are aware of the flow control issues involved with child process communication, but not all have the patience or skills to write a fully correct and deadlock-free select loop. This means that many Python applications contain race conditions. A `communicate()` method in the standard library solves this problem.

---

> Is there a way to have a bash process running in the background continuously and then the python calls could just go directly to that process?

Sure, you can still use `subprocess.Popen` and send messages to you subprocess and receive messages back without terminating the subprocess. In the simplest case your messages can be lines.

This allows for request-response style protocols as well as publish-subscribe when the subprocess can keep sending you messages back when an event of interest happens.

Comment: How to import communicate? From where to import? Can you elaborate

Comment: @Tessaracter https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 12):

> I feel this would optimize the calls a bit as there is no bash process setup and teardown.

`subprocess` never runs the shell unless you ask it explicitly e.g.,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['ls', '-l'])
```

This call runs `ls` program without invoking `/bin/sh`.

> Or will it give no performance advantage?

If your subprocess calls actually use the shell e.g., to [specify a pipeline consicely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279) or you use [bash process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28840575/4279) that could be verbose and error-prone to define using `subprocess` module directly **then it is unlikely that invoking `bash` is a performance bottleneck** -- measure it first.

There are Python packages that too allow to specify such commands consicely e.g., [`plumbum` could be used to emulate a shell pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/4279).

If you want to use `bash` as a server process then [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html) is useful for dialog-based interactions with an external process -- though it is unlikely that it affects time performance. [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/) allows to run both local and remote commands (`ssh`).

There are other subprocess wrappers such as [`sarge`](http://pythonhosted.org/sarge/overview.html#what-is-sarge-for) which can parse a pipeline specified in a string without invoking the shell e.g., it enables [cross-platform support for bash-like syntax (`&&`, `||`, `&` in command lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032170/4279) or [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) -- a complete `subprocess` replacement on Unix that provides TTY by default (it seems full-featured but [the shell-like piping is less straightforward](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#advanced-piping)). You can even use Python-ish BASHwards-looking syntax to run commands with [`xonsh`](http://xonsh.org/) shell.
Again, it is unlikely that it affects performance in a meaningful way in most cases.

The problem of starting and communicating with external processes in a portable manner is complex -- the interaction between processes, pipes, ttys, signals, threading, async. IO, buffering in various places has rough edges. Introducing a new package may complicate things if you don't know how a specific package solve numerous issues related to running shell commands.